# What exactly does "ar" utility do?

Tags: c, unix

I don't really understand what `ar` utility does on Unix systems.

I know it can be somehow used for creating c libraries, but all that man page tells me is that it is used to make archives from files, which sounds similar to, for example, `tar`....

Comment: I tried manual page and I was not very wise from it... but thanks.

Comment: This is a question about programming - and the use of the `ar` command to make libraries for use by programmers when programming.  It does not belong on SuperUser.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The primary purpose is to take individual object files (`*.o`) and bundle them together into a static library file (`*.a`). The .a file contains an index that allows the linker to quickly locate symbols in the library.

Tar doesn't create files that linkers understand.

Comment: The causality kinda goes the other direction: the original unix linker was written to use the "ar" utility to store its libraries.  It was only later that the "tar" utility became popular, largely because of better interoperability with tape devices.

Answer (score 4):

`ar` is a general purpose archiver, just like `tar`. It just "happens" to be used mostly for creating static library archives, one of its traditional uses, but you can still use it for general purpose archiving, though `tar` would probably be a better choice. `ar` is also used for Debian `.deb` packages.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly, ar is an archiver. It simply takes a set of object files (*.o) and put them in an archive that you call a static library.

Comment: ...because `tar` was used for storing files to **tape** (hence the 't'). It's no use having your libraries on a tape - you'd have to wait for the operator to mount the correct volume, just to link your program.

Answer (score 1):

It takes code in the form of object files (.obj, .o, etc) and makes a static library (archive).  The library can then be included when linking with ld to include the object code into your executable.

Take a look at the example usage in the [Wikipedia article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ar_%28Unix%29)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to run `man ar` to get the full picture. [Here](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ar)'s a copy of that on the web.

To quote:

> The  GNU  ar program creates, modifies, and extracts from archives.  An
>          archive is a single file holding a  collection  of  other  files  in  a
>          structure  that  makes  it possible to retrieve the original individual
>          files (called members of the archive).
>
> `ar` is  considered  a  binary utility because archives of this sort are
>          most often used as libraries holding commonly needed subroutines.

Answer (score 1):

ar is specifically for archives (or libraries) of object code; tar is for archives of arbitrary files. Anybody's guess why GNU refers to these as 'archives', in other environments this utility is called the 'librarian', and the resulting files just libraries.